# CocoaPod Podspec Dependency On couchbase-lite-ios

Tags: ios, cocoapods, couchbase-lite

I have a podspec with the below dependency:

```
s.dependency "couchbase-lite-ios", "~> 1.0"
```

When I lint the spec file, I get:

```
pod spec lint --no-clean
...
fatal error: 'CouchbaseLite/CouchbaseLite.h' file not found
```

Unlike the other dependencies I'm using, this pod contains a framework instead of .h/.m files. The podspec for `couchbase-lite-ios` was just updated, so I assume it's still valid.

[image]

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/3ed275b616b387671fd39e4a4c963c35182b1067/Specs/couchbase-lite-ios/1.0.3/couchbase-lite-ios.podspec.json

I've been trying to figure this out for a while. Does anyone have any idea what the cause could be?

Also, if I do `pod install` and build the project, everything get's linked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
#import <CouchbaseLite/CouchbaseLite.h>
```

to

```
#import "CouchbaseLite.h"
```